# Can ping one PC but not the other on same VPN network

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I've connected to a VPN network but I'm unable to access files from one of the PC.

What can be the problem?

[image: This is the result of the ping]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you successfully created your VPN connection. I would disable firewalls on both devices first and see if that helps.

First you will want to make sure the default rule was enabled to begin with. When that still fails it's usually because a connection profile gets set to public when the default firewall rule wants it to be set to private (or domain). Even if the regular connection is private, when VPNs first connect often the VPN connections default to public. So the default firewall rules, even if enabled/allowed, won't let in pings or SMB requests. I would double-check the profile on both connections and maybe make custom rules for inbound pings and SMB requests.

#### Checking Network Profile Setting:

In PowerShell:

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile
```

You should get something like this:

```
Name             : YourConnectionName
InterfaceAlias   : Wi-Fi
InterfaceIndex   : 19
NetworkCategory  : Private
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic

Name             : VPNConnectionName
InterfaceAlias   : VPNConnectionName
InterfaceIndex   : 37
NetworkCategory  : Private
IPv4Connectivity : NoTraffic
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic
```

Command to change either if you need it:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -Name "YourConnectionName" -NetworkCategory Private
```

#### Making a Custom Rule

You might want to do this just to make sure it's working if you don't want to take your firewall down for security reasons.

```
Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Settings >
Inbound Rules > New Inbound Rule >
CUSTOM > ALL PROGRAMS >
Protocol: ICMPv4 ... Customize ... Specific ICMP Types [Check] Echo 
Request ... OK >
Local: Any IP/Remote: Valid VPN IP Scope >
Allow > All Profiles >
(Give it a name...) > Finish
```

If you wanted to do SMB instead, you could do port 445 TCP+UPD for the protocol.

Comment: The VPN connection is set to private, file and printer sharing has been enabled. What's confusing is how am I able to access 200.200.200.102 but not 200.200.200.109? These 2 are the remote PCs and 200.200.200.109 is the VPN server.

Comment: You're right, if you've got at least a 1way ping working, your VPN connection is up and this is probably something face-palmy. Have you tried disabling both the firewalls to see if that works yet? Also I'd run "Get-NetConnectionProfile" in powershell on your client just to make sure.

Comment: Both profiles are Private but under IPv4 for my VPN is "Internet" but yours is "No Traffic". I disabled the firewall, no change.

Comment: From your answer above it sounds like you just hadn't enabled the rule yet. Glad you found it, it's a long list. One more tip, rather than allowing connections from the Internet, you could make the VPN IP address in a private-scope IP range. So you could use 192.168.200.x/24, for instance, which would avoid potentially letting other people from the Internet in, while also making sure you don't block yourself from accessing various websites in Brazil.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this did the trick but....

On the VPN Server

Instead of making a custom rule, Windows Firewall had a profile for "File and Printer Sharing (ICMPv4)", I allowed that through the firewall.

Also, for "Network Discovery (UPnP-In)" I allowed that through the firewall and added "Internet" to the Scope.

Restarted the PC, now I am able to access files on \\200.200.200.109.